# Speech to text Android api for Indian languages

Tags: android

I am looking for an Android API for converting Indian (like Hindi or tamil)  language speech to text ?

If there is no API support, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "hi_IN")` for `Hindi` language.

**Try this:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;
 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
 
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
    private TextView txtSpeechInput;
    private ImageButton btnSpeak;
    private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
        txtSpeechInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput);
        btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
 
        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                promptSpeechInput();
            }
        });
 
    }
 
    /**
     * Showing google speech input dialog
     * */
    private void promptSpeechInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "hi_IN");

        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
 
    /**
     * Receiving speech input
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
 
                ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }
 
        }
    }     
}
```

Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/). Hope this will help~

Comment: Will this program takes Hindi speech as input and provide me the output in Hindi language text (not English) ?

Comment: @JohnsonTummalapalli Thanks for accepting my answer. If it seems useful, I hope you will give an up-vote too. Thank you :)

Comment: Not getting text in hindi fonts

Answer (score 1):

intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "hin-IND");

change to

intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "hi-IN");

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated working method (2020)

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048466/google-speech-to-text-extra-language-set-to-kn-but-not-working) answer, for Indian languages, try using it in the format:
`<lang-code>_IN`

Example:-

> `recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,"hi_IN")`

Using `EXTRA_LANGUAGE`, not `EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE` works for me.